# How to change Vertical Alignment of Text in TextBox Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

How to set `VerticalAlignment` of `Text` which entered in `TextBox`. `TextBox` only have `TextAlignment` property which use to set Text alignment horizontally only.

XAML:

```
<TextBox MinWidth="300" MinHeight="45" TextAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

[image]

**EDIT**

After adding `VerticalContentAlignment` property XAML looks like:

```
<TextBox VerticalContentAlignment="Center" />
<TextBox  VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"/>
<PasswordBox VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

Output:

[image]

Clearly property `VerticalContentAlignment` not working. Anything I am missing here?

Comment: @w.b I thinks setting padding only option to set vertical margin..

Comment: [VerticalContentAlignment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control.verticalcontentalignment)

Comment: @ChrisW. Looks like `VerticalContentAlignment` not working!

Comment: Looks like you're right, if we go look at the [default style template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj710191.aspx) sure enough they dont have that property bound like they say in the docs (imagine that). So what you can do is go add `VerticalAlignment={TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}` to the `ContentControl` in the style template.

Comment: were you able to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

I have the answer for your prayers.. :-) What you do is simply to change the default style for the TextBox... Since you remove the scrollviewer, i guess its not possible to use more lines.. I did not need that functionality though... :)

Original TextBox Style:

```
 <!-- Default style for Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBox -->
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinWidth}" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinHeight}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxForegroundThemeBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="SelectionHighlightColor" Value="{ThemeResource TextSelectionHighlightColorThemeBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxBorderThemeBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderThemeThickness}" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlFontSize}" />
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="NoWrap" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemePadding}" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlMarginThemeThickness}" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                <Grid Background="Transparent">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledBorderThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledHeaderForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0"
                                                     To="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderThemeOpacity}" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                Value="{ThemeResource TextSelectionHighlightColorThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="0" />
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxFocusedBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Border x:Name="BorderElement" Grid.Row="1" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" />
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter" Grid.Row="0"
                                      Style="{StaticResource HeaderContentPresenterStyle}"
                                      Margin="{ThemeResource TextControlHeaderMarginThemeThickness}"
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" />
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement" Grid.Row="1"
                                  MinHeight="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinHeight}"
                                  HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}"
                                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                  VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}"
                                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                  IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}"
                                  IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}"
                                  IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}"
                                  Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                  Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" IsTabStop="False" ZoomMode="Disabled"
                                  AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />
                    <ContentControl x:Name="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Grid.Row="1"
                                    Foreground="{ThemeResource TextBoxPlaceholderTextThemeBrush}"
                                    FontSize="{ThemeResource ContentControlFontSize}"
                                    Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                    IsTabStop="False" Content="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

New Style :

```
<Style x:Key="ContentCenteredTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinWidth}" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinHeight}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxForegroundThemeBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="SelectionHighlightColor" Value="{ThemeResource TextSelectionHighlightColorThemeBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxBorderThemeBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderThemeThickness}" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlFontSize}" />
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="NoWrap" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemePadding}" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlMarginThemeThickness}" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                <Grid Background="Transparent">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledBorderThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledHeaderForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0"
                                                     To="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderThemeOpacity}" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                Value="{ThemeResource TextSelectionHighlightColorThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="0" />
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxFocusedBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Border x:Name="BorderElement" Grid.Row="1" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" />
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter" Grid.Row="0"
                                      Style="{StaticResource HeaderContentPresenterStyle}"
                                      Margin="{ThemeResource TextControlHeaderMarginThemeThickness}"
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" />
                    <ContentControl x:Name="ContentElement" Grid.Row="1"
                                  MinHeight="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinHeight}"
                                   VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                  Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                   IsTabStop="False"
                                  AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />
                    <ContentControl x:Name="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Grid.Row="1"
                                    Foreground="{ThemeResource TextBoxPlaceholderTextThemeBrush}"
                                    FontSize="{ThemeResource ContentControlFontSize}"
                                    VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                    Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                    IsTabStop="False" Content="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Your welcome :-)

Comment: what an extremely complicated process for a very simple achievement